# Is it a bad practice to define a method receiver on an empty struct?

Tags: go

I saw some code that contains a method receiver on an empty struct. Is it a bad coding practice in Go?

```golang
type Example struct {
    // no attribute
}

func (e *Example) DoSomething() error {
    return nil
}
```

Shall I recommend him to use Go function instead, but with what justification?

```golang
func DoSomething() error {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The method receiver in your example isn't an empty struct, it's a pointer to an empty struct.

Comment: Additionally to what @gonutz said, it also gives you some flexiblity later on when it suddenly occurs to you that some attributes might be useful when running `DoSomething`. Especially if `Example` has many methods.

Comment: It can be very good practice. It depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

It can make sense, e.g. in case you want to implement an interface, you **need** a type to do it. An empty struct might be necessary in that case.

```
type SomethingDoer interface {
    DoSomething() error
}

// Example implements the SomethingDoer interface.
type Example struct {
    // no attribute
}

func (e *Example) DoSomething() error {
    return nil
}

// A line like the following is sometimes used to assert
// that a type implements a specific interface.
var _ SomethingDoer = &Example{}
```

Also, as mentioned by @NotX, sometimes you are in the middle on constructing a larger thing and you might make it a type right away because you know that down the line you want to add state to it. I personally stay away from this kind of "defensive programming" and would add a type only when needed. But styles and opinions differ, so it is not uncommon.

Comment: I agree with the scenario mentioned in above answer and what @NotX added in comment section. If It is out of these two scenarios, Is it good to avoid having it?